# React showing a blank screen without any error messages (context api used)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state

I'm building a react Amazon clone, so in order to give the user the ability to add a product into his basket (as the first version of all the future checkout system), I've used Context Api to manage this.

When I finished writing Context Api code and adding it to the `index.js` file so I could access the data I got a blank screen with absolutely no error messages. I don't know where is exactly the problem.

StateProvider.js

```
import React , { createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react'

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({reducer , initialValue, children}) => {
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialValue)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
};

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

reducer.js

```
export const initialState = {
    basket: [], 
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
            return{
                ...state,
                basket: [...state.basket, ...action.item]
            };
            default: 
            return state;
    };
};

export default reducer;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { StateProvider } from './Special_components/StateProvider';
import reducer, { initialState } from './Special_components/reducer';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <StateProvider reducer={reducer} initialState={initialState} >
            <App />
        </StateProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>

)
```

Comment: You are not passing any `reducer` or `initialState` props to the `StateProvider` component. What debugging steps have you taken to figure out why nothing is rendered? Are you *sure* there are no error messages in the console? How are you running the app?

Comment: I just changed my code and pass them to the ```StateProvider``` component, and I still have the same problem, yes there are no error messages.

Comment: in order to debug, the first thing I did is to check the console, when I saw no errors I tried to read my code again (perhaps there is a variable that is not calling right, or maybe I forgot about something simple), later I checked the ```index.js``` component to make sure that there is nothing wrong and I checked for every piece of my code to make sure that everything is working fine. after all of this, I rewrite the code from scratch. after all of this, I still have the same problem with absolutely no idea what caused it so I posted this question.

Comment: I don't see any overt issues in the code you've shared. Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: actually, i just re-write the code with different logic and stricter and it works! , I will answer my question later when I'm free to help others who may have the same problem, thank you for your assistance btw <3.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're providing props to the wrong component.
Try this in `index.js`:

```
...

<StateProvider reducer={reducer} initialValue={initialState}>
  <App />
</StateProvider>

...
```

Also note how I renamed the prop to `initialValue` because that's what your `StateProvider` is expecting.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0):

You forgot  to add return in your StateProvider function

```
    export const StateProvider = ({reducer , initialValue, children}) => {
return (
 <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialValue)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
)}
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change arrow ES6 {} => () because {} need return

```
export const StateProvider = ({reducer , initialValue, children}) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialValue)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
);
```